# Type Error string indicies must be integers, not str

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am stuck on a simple problem;
The variable twitter is a pandas dataset array
I am trying to filter away twitter['sentiment'] == 0, but in the code below I am getting the error message; "Type Error string indicies must be integers, not str"
How do I fix this?

```
twitter['sentiment'] = twitter['full_text'].map(lambda text: TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity)
twitter1 = list(filter(lambda x: x['sentiment'] == 0, twitter))
```

Comment: Can you show the full error including the stack trace?

Comment: it looks like `twitter` is a dictionary (you use it as so in the first line), the error comes from accessing `x['sentiment']` because mapping over a dictionary called `dict.__iter__` which simply iterates over the keys of the dictionary - thus you are indexing a dict key (a str) with a str (which is the error). If you want tweet text that where polarity is `0` then use `[tweet for tweet, sentiment in zip(twitter['full_text'], twitter['sentiment']) if sentiment == 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this simple answer worked.

> twitter1 = twitter[twitter.sentiment != 0]

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
twitter1 = list(filter(lambda x: x['sentiment'] == 0, twitter))
```

is equivalent to this comprehension syntax:

```
twitter1 = [x for x in twitter if x['sentiment'] == 0]
```

which is roughly equivalent to:

```
twitter1 = []
for x in twitter:
    if x['sentiment'] == 0:
        twitter1.append(x)
```

The `for x in twitter` loop iterates over the keys of the `twitter` dictionary, which I presume to be strings. `x['sentiment']` then attempts to index those strings with another string, which isn't an operation that makes sense, so it raises an error.

Comment: I get an error message saying "string integers must be integers"